# ValueError when instantiating LineString from a mix of tuples and Point objects

Tags: point, geometry, linestring, shapely

I'm new to Shapely, and tried instantiating a LineString object from a mix of tuples and Point objects like this:

```
>>> LineString([Point(1,2),(2,3),Point(3,4),(5,5)])
```

I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/Python/2.7/shapely/geometry/linestring.py", line 46, in __init__
    self._set_coords(coordinates)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/Python/2.7/shapely/geometry/linestring.py", line 70, in _set_coords
    self._geom, self._ndim = geos_linestring_from_py(coordinates)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/Python/2.7/shapely/geometry/linestring.py", line 228, in geos_linestring_from_py
    "Input %s is the wrong shape for a LineString" % str(ob))
ValueError: Input [<shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x1057570d0>, (2, 3), <shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x105e69690>, (5, 5)] is the wrong shape for a LineString
```

According to [lines 19-22 of the test script](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/master/shapely/tests/test_linestring.py), it's supposed to be able to handle this mix of different objects. Any ideas if this 'feature' is actually implemented? Or should I be sticking to homogeneous class types when instantiating a new LineString object?

p.s. Running python 2.7.5, shapely 1.3.0, Mac OS X 10.9.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you need at least version 1.3.2 of Shapely, which was released 2014-05-13.

The lines of code you are looking at were added in a commit "[Allow LineStrings to take arrays of Points](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/commit/bb65311a9206140c0518299a314acfa23c8829f1#diff-eed1565841ab6fd0182c0b8c3a3853a8)".